# How to generate a component in the template dynamically

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have written a custom svelte component. Now, I wanted to create an element of that in another class using javascript. How can I do that? Following is the code that I wanted to make it work:

```
<script>
    import component2 from "./Component2.svelte";

    function abc() {
        var element = document.createElement("component2");
        document.getElementById("abc").appendChild(element);
    }
</script>

<div id="abc" use:abc>dsaads</div>
```

Here is a working [example](https://svelte.dev/repl/e6d8e252ebfc48dea3fa42ba8d5aae57?version=3.9.1).

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a client-side component using Svelte itself rather than using plain JS. (Source: [docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#Creating_a_component))

Simply change your `abc` function like below

```
<script>
    import Component2 from "./Component2.svelte";

    function abc() {
        const element = new Component2({
            target: document.querySelector('#abc')
        })
    }
</script>

<div id="abc" use:abc>dsaads</div>
```

This will append the component as the last child of the `<div id="abc"></div>`

Here is a working [example](https://svelte.dev/repl/308ca289b03c487aaec45158f0a177da?version=3.9.1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way I can create a custom component in JS without giving target? I want to just create a function which would just return the element and not deciding where it would come.